# Sort array based on constantly changing map

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a ConcurrentHashMap which is asynchronously updated to mirror the data in a database. I am attempting to sort an array based on this data which works fine most of the time but if the data updates while sorting then things can get messy.

I have thought of copying the map and then sorting with the copied map but due to the frequency I need to sort and the size of the map this is not a possibility.

Comment: What about ConurrentSkipListMap, this is concurrent and sorted.

Comment: @PeterLawrey The map doesn't need to be sorted, it just needs to be 'frozen' while the sorting takes place.

Comment: @user2248702 If the frequency in which you need to get a sorted copy of the map is high enough, you don't want to sort "on demand", and would be better off to keep the map sorted all the time.

Comment: @Eran It is not the map I would like to be sorted, it is multiple arrays which are sorted based on the content of the map.

Comment: @user2248702 In that case you should consider maintaining these arrays sorted instead of computing them on demand. It's hard to give a specific answer without seeing your code.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add a lock which prevents the map from being updated in other threads while you're sorting your array.

Comment: @nickgroenke How would a lock usually be implemented? Does a ConcurrentHashMap or any other form of multithreaded map include one?

Comment: The concurrent collections don't expose a lock for your use.  Either you use a collection which is already sorted, or you sort on demand which will be *much* slower which you do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood your requirements perfectly, so I'll deal with two separate cases.
Let's say your async "update" operation requires you to update 2 keys in your map.
Scenario 1 is : it's OK if a "sort" operation occurs while only 1 of the two updates is visible.
Scenario 2 is : you need the 2 updates to be visible simultaneously or not at all (which is called atomic behavior).

## Case 1 : you do not need atomic bulk updates

In this case, `ConcurrentHashMap` is OK as is, seeing iterators are guaranteed not to fail upon modification of the map. From `ConcurrentHashMap` documentation (emphasis mine) :

> Similarly, Iterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the state of the hash table at some point at **or since** the creation of the iterator/enumeration. They do not throw ConcurrentModificationException. However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.

So you are guaranteed that you can iterate through the map even while it is being modified without the iteration crashing for concurrent modifications. But (see the emphasis) you are NOT guaranteed that all modifications made concurrently to the map are immediately visible not even if only part of them are, and in which order.

## Case 2 : you need bulk updates to be atomic

Further more with `ConcurrentHashMap`, you do not have any guarantee that bulk operations (`putAll`) will behave atomically :

> For aggregate operations such as putAll and clear, concurrent retrievals may reflect insertion or removal of only some entries.

So I see two scenarios for working this case, each of which entail locking.

### Solution 1 : building a copy

Building a "frozen" copy can help you **only if** this copy is built during a phase where all other updates are locked, because the copying of your map implies iterating through it, and our hypothesis is that iteration is not safe if we have concurrent modification.

This could look like :

```
ConcurrentMap<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>(); //
AtomicReference<Map<String, String>> frozenCopy = new AtomicReference<Map<String, String>>(map); 

public void sortOperation() {
    sortUsingFrozenCopy();
}

public void updateOperation() {
    synchronized (map) { // Exclusive access to the map instance
        updateMap();
        Map<String, String> newCopy = new HashMap<String, String>();
        newCopy.putAll(map); // You build the copy. This is safe thanks to the exclusive access.
        frozenCopy.set(newCopy); // And you update the reference to the copy
    }
}
```

This solution could be refined...
Seeing your 2 operations (map read and map writes) are totally asynchronous, one can assume that your read operations can not know (and should not care) wether the previous write operation occured 0.1 sec before or will occur 0.1 sec after.
So having your read operations depend on a "frozen copy" of the map that is actually updated once every 1 (or 2, or 5, or 10) seconds (or update events) instead of each time may be a possibility for your case.

### Solution 2 : lock the map for updates

Locking the Map without copying it is a solution. You'd want a `ReadWriteLock` (or `StampedLock` in Java 8) so as to have multiple sorts possible, and a mutual exclusion of read and write operations.

Solution 2 is actually easy to implement. You'd have something like

```
ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public void sortOperation() {
    lock.readLock().lock();
            // read lock granted, which prevents writeLock to be granted
    try {
        sort(); // This is safe, nobody can write
    } finally {
        lock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}

public void updateOperation() {
    lock.writeLock().lock();
            // Write lock granted, no other writeLock (except to myself) can be granted
            // nor any readLock
    try {
        updateMap(); // Nobody is reading, that's OK.
    } finally {
        lock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```

With a `ReadWriteLock`, multiple reads can occur simultaneously, or a single write, but not multiple writes nor reads and writes.
You'd have to consider the possibility of using a fair variant of the lock, so that you are sure that every read and write process will eventually have a chance of being executed, depending on your usage pattern.

(NB : if you use Locking/synchronized, your Map may not need to be concurrent, as write and read operations will be exclusive, but this is another topic).

Comment: I think a lock is the best solution. As the map is often written to by multiple threads is there a way that I could make it so that I can write with multiple threads but when locked it is read-only?

Comment: @user2248702 : not sure I understand. You want multiple concurrent writes possible (with no read at all) or the contrary ? What I don't get is that you seem not to be OK with non atomic updates but you are OK with simultaneous writes. This is not logic to me. If "write 1" updates keys A and B, and "write 2" updates keys A and C, with multiple writes, you can not predict what the state of A will be after updates. How this that compatible with the fact that, for your "sort" operations, you can not tolerate writes to be partially visible ?

Comment: I want multiple concurrent writes to be possible at the same time as reads but I also want to be able to lock the state (no writes, only reads) for operations which require a constant state. The lock needs to be blocking so that all threads that attempt to change the data while locked will change it at the soonest possible time after the lock is released.

Comment: I see no easy solution for that. I guess a double lock pattern could work... But I insist this almost make no sense. Scenario 1 is : you have 1 update that updates keys A and B.
Scenario 2 : you have update 1 that involves keys A and B, and update 2 that involves key B only.
Well "non atomic case 1" (which you said is KO) and "concurrent case 2" (which you seek) are one and the same : you can not know what the B key will be associated to at any point in between the process. What makes sense at one point would be different 1/2 sec earlier. Draw timelines, explore the combinations, you'll see...